# How do you get Dijkstra's treasure back?

Tags: the-witcher-3

So there must be a way to get the location where Menge stashed the treasure, because Dijkstra can provide support for the Kaer Morhen battle. The problem is, all the guides and/or walkthroughs I've located online just say "go all the way through the conversation with Menge." I've done that, several times, and still Geralt is left looking at Dijkstra going "Uhhhh, I dunno where the treasure is."

Specifically, the guides say which dialogue options to use, up to "Witchers will do anything for gold." Then they say to ask after the treasure, and Menge will just tell you. When *I* do it, Menge essentially goes "Lol, why would I tell you that?" I'll check again, but I'm away from my Witcher 3 capable PC for another few days.

How do I discover it's location so I don't piss Dijkstra off?

Comment: Probably with a search algorithm.

Comment: @DCShannon Sadly, not enough people will understand this.

Answer (score 3):

In order to find out Dijkstra's treasure location you have to keep questioning Menge and act all indifferent to Triss's torture. Even though he knows you and Triss are more than friends you have to say that this is payback and keep questioning Menge.

**Nevertheless, don't worry, Dijkstra will only act pissed off in the moment but it won't break off your relationship with him... he will still help you and ask for a even a bigger favour later. Nothing changes!**

Comment: Hmm, let me replay that part... but like I said this doesn't matter at all in the grand scheme of things! No reason to downvote.

Comment: Yeah, actually it is possible to get the location... I just talked to Menge and let Triss be tortured until I Menge told me the location. Couldn't let Triss be tortured before. Will update my answer

Comment: @Dallium Why did you delete your comment? Were you able to do this?